# Prefix is not adding for "xmlns" when Convert xsd to xml using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to convert xsd to xml using XmlSampleGenerator**(Microsoft.Xml.XMLGen)**,prefix is not not added for targetNamespace.
    Sample xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  targetNamespace="http://fed.com/ws/open/v15">
  <xs:element name="CreateRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>        
       <xs:element name="ClientDetail">
          <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element type="xs:int" name="AccountNumber" />
           <xs:element type="xs:int" name="MeterNumber" />
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>      
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

```
 Converted Xml:


<CreateRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://fed.com/ws/openship/v15">
TargetNamespace url is converted to 
<xmlns="http://fed.com/ws/openship/v15">
```

it is not have prefix like "xmlns:xsd" because of this select xpath is not 
   working

I am use this code to xpath account number

```
       var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
        xml.LoadXml(test.xml)
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
        instance");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("v15", "http://fed.com/ws/openship/v15");
        var nodes =xml.SelectNodes("/CreateRequest/ClientDetail[1]/AccountNumber[1]", nsmgr);
```

Comment: The prefixes need to be in the xpath if they are in the document...

Comment: Thanks @TonyHopkinson  Is it possible to add prefix for targetNamespace="http://fed.com/ws/open/v15" ? The xsd have the same url as targetNamespace

Comment: Hard to see from this but it's so you can reference any entities defined in the xsd